# Why is my property readonly in winforms editor?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, axhost

My **class A** inherits a **class B** that inherits **AxHost**.

My property is shown as readonly with no attributes set that would enforce this behaviour.

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

My property was missing a DispId Attribute.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispId(96859268)]
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

[DispID must be unique across interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216107/dispid-must-be-unique-across-interfaces)

**Further questions:**
In my example, Class B does have some Properties tagged with DispId and some without, and those without are not affected by being readonly. 
If someone has an explanation for this, please share it.